# Drawing extremely slow and cancels

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, performance

I'm working on a series of maps and whenever I select a symbol, or pan, or anything my whole map has to redraw.  It is a very slow redraw.  I generally have to wait 5-10 seconds, even if I am just selecting one symbol to move.  Also, it doesn't draw everything, so I think I have moved all the grills from behind trees, but inevitably there is always one that does not draw.  The imagery I am using as a basemap is a very large raster, though even when I turn it off, it still takes a good chunk of time redrawing.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?  I thought it might be the graphics card but I'm not sure how to tell or if it might be another issue.

Here are my computer stats:
Operating System: Windows10 Enterprise 64-bit
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.3GHz
Memory: 8000MB RAM
For both monitors:
   Name: Interl(R) HD Graphics 4600
   Device Type: Full Display Device
   Approx. Total Memory: 4167 MB
   Current Display Mode: 1920 x 1080 (32 bit) (60 Hz)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  Please tell us a bit more about your maps - how many layers, what type of features, where are the feature classes stored?  Is your basemap raster a image file, or from a database?  Is it cached?  What version of ArcMap are you using?  Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information.